# @input and @output decorator change event

Tags: angular

Going through some code of `@input\@output` decorator I found different behaviour.

In below code, there is `counter` component gets its value from parent `app` component via `@input` decorator and emit change via `@output` decorator.

**My question :**

1. Why change event is calling when I manually typing value in textbox.?, whereas I defined `this.change.emit(this.count);` only inside `Increment\Decrement` function. ?
2. When I make changes through `Increment\Decrement` button, I get the correct changed value in `app` component (parent), **but** when I manually type value, then I get `[object Event]` not typed number. Why So ?

Code is below [**Plunker is here.**](https://plnkr.co/edit/l4rxzWCmqsC4fgzf5S83?p=preview)

**counter component:**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'counter',
  template: `
    <div class="counter">
      <button (click)="decrement()">
        Decrement
      </button>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="count">
      <button (click)="increment()">
        Increment
      </button>
    </div>
  `
export class CounterComponent {  
  @Input()
  count: number = 0;

  @Output()
  change: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  increment() {
    this.count++;
    this.change.emit(this.count);
  }

  decrement() {
    this.count--;
    this.change.emit(this.count);
  }  
}
```

**app component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div class="app">
      <counter
        [count]="myCount"
        (change)="countChange($event)">
      </counter>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  myCount: number = 10;
  countChange(event) {
    console.log(event); //log Event object below
    console.log('change called...!!!');
    this.myCount = event; 
  }
}
```

I tried to change input type to **`number`** as well, also changed binding to 1 way : `[ngModel]="count"` but doesn't seem to be working.

**console.log(event);**

> Event  {isTrusted: true, type: "change", target:
>   input.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-dirty, currentTarget: counter,
>   eventPhase: 3…}

Comment: Replace event name with something other than `change`. It's standart event which is bubbling https://plnkr.co/edit/kcRcSh8tAt4BMt81GvP0?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui : Thanks !!.., please post your comment as answer, I'll  mark it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main idea of angular when working with events is the ability to use any of standart DOM event in addition to build-in `@Output` event.

So when you write

```
(change)="handler($event)"
```

angular will call `handler` for both cases:

- when you have `@Output() change` and called `change.emit()`
- when standart `change` event has fired on input element

So replace your `@Output` event to something other than `change` and then it should work as you expect.

**[Fixed Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kcRcSh8tAt4BMt81GvP0?p=preview)**

Comment: I was trying to debug this issue wherein I found that if I removed the `@Input` decorator from the child component and assigned it to public and removed the `[count]="myCount"`, the code seems to be working fine. I did nothing to the `(change)` handler. I am still trying to figure out how that worked?

Comment: When you're manually typing value in input `$event` is `Event` object because it is raised from standart DOM event. When you click on Decrement/Increment button `$event` is that what you pass in  `this.change.emit(this.count);`

Comment: I changed number in input and see the following https://monosnap.com/file/C9Yqi7AuVyypfcMJaRdIsPEbisZgAt

Comment: Another doubt, doesn't the increment and decrement operator on the model serve as a `change` event?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147245/discussion-between-sriram-jayaraman-and-yurzui).